# Convert String to Date and calculate date difference

Tags: java, android

How can I convert this String to Date:
String time = "2017-07-27T02:52:36.05768Z";

My code didn't work

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
try{
 date = dateFormat.parse(time);
} catch (ParseException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
 Logi(TAG, e.getMessage());
}
```

I receive the error:

```
error: Unparseable date: "2017-07-27T02:52:36.05768Z" (at offset 10)
```

Note that I have try to research before asking but nothing works. Thank you
[Solved] Wrong date string format. The string should match date pattern

Comment: The string you are trying to parse not the valid format for `"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Ben P. you should use a formatter like:

`SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSZ");`

yyyy- for year
MM- for month
dd- for day
HH - for hours
mm - for minutes 
ss - for seconds
SSSSS - for milliseconds

Refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for examples.

Comment: I receive that string from the REST server

Comment: Okay, well as folks have mentioned, you have two options... 

1) Change the format of the date string itself to match your formatter 
2) Change your formatter to match your date string

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern doesn't match your input. You have a space where your input has a "T", and you don't have anything to match the period, the nanoseconds, or the "Z" at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You Must change your time to

String time = "**2017-07-27 02:52:36.05768Z**"

ex :

```
public static String ViewEAEA(){
    String s = "";
    String time = "2017-07-27 02:52:36.05768Z";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    try{
    Date date = dateFormat.parse(time);
    s = dateFormat.format(date);
    System.out.println(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
    return s;
}
```

output :

2017-07-27 02:52:36

Comment: is there any problem if I remove the 'T' from the string

Comment: np bro, it is better for me

Answer (score 0):

This date is in W3C XML Schema date/time format. You can parse it using javax.xml.datatype package:

```
    XMLGregorianCalendar c = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar("2017-07-27T02:52:36.05768Z");
    Date date = c.toGregorianCalendar().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method tailored for your string :

```
public Date stringToDate(String time) throws ParseException {
    time = time.replace('T', ' ');
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
}
```

or you can just modify your formatter :

```
public Date stringToDate(String time) throws ParseException {
    return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").parse(time);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly it is saying that offset(10) you have character that cannot be changed to date format. If you see carefully at index 10 you have 'To' and it is text not a part of date time format. So split and concatinate your date string so that you can remove that 'To' text from that string.

Comment: that is T and zero i guess. So its not a problem as you stated

Answer (score 0):

Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern string. Your pattern in SimpleDateFormat constructor was not perfect with corresponding 
to your data time string. So let's try this code.

```
String time = "2017-07-27T02:52:36.05768Z";
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
try {
Date date = parser.parse(time);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(date);
System.out.println("The date is " + formattedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I hope it will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")` and try.